# how to finalize/flush write/close after openWrite

Tags: dart

This code is trying to open an existing file, then add text to it via openWrite.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  File inFile = new File('/tmp/foo.txt');
  String currentText = inFile.readAsStringSync();
  var writer = inFile.openWrite();
  writer.write(currentText);
  writer.write("\nOne more line");
  writer.close();
  exit(0);
}
```

After completion the file is empty. If the exit(0) is not there it works fine.
What call(s) should be done to ensure all writes are written before exit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the writer is async, you will want to use the [done](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/IOSink.html#done) property of the writer to be notified when the writing and closing of the stream is done. For instance:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  File inFile = new File('/tmp/foo.txt');
  String currentText = inFile.readAsStringSync();
  var writer = inFile.openWrite();
  writer.write(currentText);
  writer.write("\nOne more line");
  writer.close();
  writer.done.then((_) {
    exit(0);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://api.dart.dev/be/180361/dart-io/IOSink/close.html), data may be buffered, you shoud `await writer.flush();` to make sure data  is written to file.